# Will sending same transaction from multiple node increase its chances of going through?

Tags: transactions

Will a user have a better chance of winning this game if they send the same transactions from multiple nodes simultaneously  ?

```
function win( address player, unit bet ) constant returns(bool) {
    require( tx.gasprice <= 50000000000 wei );
    require( now > gameStartTime) ;
    require( endgame == false  );

    if( bet == theanswer ) 
    {
        endgame = true; 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When testing from two different machines on 2 different networks geth sendTransaction to the contract address returned the same tx id. not sure how that could happen.

Comment: If it's a race to call this function, then in all likelihood (as in, under common situations), sending the transaction via multiple nodes will increase the odds of being first to call the function, all else equal. One is more likely to have lower latency to the node that mines the relevant block (by having a shorter path).

Comment: I tried that from 2 different machines, but the tx number was the same.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Not sure how the tx number (ID?) is related to your question.

Comment: My understanding, if you send this tx from 2 different clients, one of them should fail because only one is allowed to win. I add the test to the question.